# pygatt NotificationTimeout: None

Tags: python, python-2.7, gatttool

I try to read characteristic data out of an BLE based Sensor. Therefore i use the pygatt module

```
import pygatt

adapter = pygatt.GATTToolBackend()

try:
   adapter.start()
   device = adapter.connect("2B:01:56:6C:F4:E6")
   value= device.char_read("00007502-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")

finally:
   adapter.stop()
```

Everytime i try to run this in my Linux console (with Python 2.7.16) i get an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygatt/backends/gatttool/device.py", line 17, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygatt/backends/gatttool/device.py", line 40, in char_read
    return self._backend.char_read(self, uuid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygatt/backends/gatttool/gatttool.py", line 50, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygatt/backends/gatttool/gatttool.py", line 593, in char_read
    self.sendline('char-read-uuid %s' % uuid)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygatt/backends/gatttool/gatttool.py", line 191, in event
    self.wait(event, timeout)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygatt/backends/gatttool/gatttool.py", line 157, in wait
    raise NotificationTimeout()
pygatt.exceptions.NotificationTimeout: None
```

I am completely lost on this error. Do you know how to fix this ?
Any help on this much appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Since I was facing the same problem and nobody out there seemed to have this problem...

Well, the problem was that **the requested UUID characteristic didn't exist/was invalid**. Make sure that you've typed it right or that you haven't clipped some part off when copying from putty or similar *(Totally not speaking from experience! Of course!)*

If you are pasting a characteristic UUID from the internet or a similar device, maybe your device don't have this UUID.

***OR***

This could (not tested, but should make sense) also happen if you write to an UUID which is *non-writeable* (read-only/subscribe-only).

If you're sure that everything is right and that you have triple-checked the UUID with a dedicated sniffer or simply a BLE Scanner on your Phone, then the device is probably closing the connection too fast.

***TROUBLESHOOTING:***

You can *manually* connect with the device and issue commands using:

`gatttool -I`

When you are inside the program, type:

`connect aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff`

And then, before the connection closes:

`char-read-uuid xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

and analyse what happens. If it works there, it *should* also work in python.

Comment: Holy cow! This question is from *yesterday*. The world is indeed small!